# Tomcat referencing JNDI

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

I would like to be able to reference/inject a JNDI resource into another JNDI resource, this may not be possible but thought I'd ask.

If I have the following example datasource:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/DatabaseName" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              username="dbUsername" password="dbPasswd"
              url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/dbname"
              driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
              initialSize="5" maxWait="5000"
              maxActive="120" maxIdle="5"
              validationQuery="select 1"
              poolPreparedStatements="true" />
```

How can I reference/inject this in my generic java bean resource:

```
 <Resource name="bean/MyBeanFactory" auth="Container"
            type="com.mycompany.MyBean"
            factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
            datasource=? />
```

Comment: you have to use name "jdbc/DatabaseName" try it

Comment: That will not work, it will simply hold a String not refer to the datasource